# Proof Regarding Decimal Expansions

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

Just as a precursor, I'm not a mathematics major (though I've had some experience with abstract algebra and number theory), so I have absolutely no idea how to approach this problem. Hints, not solutions, would be preferred. ^^

*Prove that every positive integer can be multiplied by a power of 2 such that the decimal expansion of the product has at least as many 8's as it has 4's.*

My first thought was, "Hey, this question seems to have a big loophole! If the decimal expansion has zero 4's, it's allowed to have zero 8's!"

But I couldn't really find a way to go down that route either. I also don't know if multiplying by ${2^0}$ is allowed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Multiplying by $2^0$ can be allowed, but is often of no use.

Comment: If my number is $.\overline {448}$ does that count?  It has infinitely many of each.

Comment: Well, I was thinking, for any number that doesn't have a 4 in it to begin with, we can just multiply by 1 to preserve the required quality. For numbers that have a 4 in just the units digit, we can attempt to multiply by 2 to convert the 4 into an 8, but we risk introducing more 4's in other decimal places. Also, to Lulu's comment, we're only considering positive integers and I think we're also only considering whole number powers of 2.

Comment: @lulu: yes it counts, as long as this is an integer.

Comment: @sss: I guess you are getting close. If you introduce more $4$'s, then doubling once again will convert them to $8$'s (this process cannot continue forever as the initial number of digits is finite). But there can be carries, that destroy them...

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, I was thinking rational.  Different problem.  Thanks.

Comment: The other thing I considered is that at most, doubling can only carry at most 1 to the next digit, so you'll never be able to create a 4 or an 8 due to carrying (because nothing doubles to 3 or 7). Since carries cannot create 4's or 8's, the only influx we have is previous 2's and 4's. However, while the 4's are very happy to become 8's, doubling the 8's ends up killing them. So there's some point at which we've lost all the 4's. That sounds like a jumbled mess, but am I on the right track?

Comment: I guess I'm rephrasing the question to say that every integer can be multiplied by a power of two such that it has zero 4's in its decimal expansion, but I don't know if that statement is true at all.

Comment: `297296612695686800340485847402419630557` is the smallest number I could find (there are doubtless many much smaller) such that multiplying it by a power of 2 leaves 4 in the decimal expansion, at least for 2^0 through 2^9999. However, there may be a larger value of 2^n for which there is no 4 in the decimal expansion.